# Why doesn't keys() and values() work on (String,String) one-pair RDD, while sortByKey() works

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I create an RDD using the README.md file in Spark directory. The type of the `newRDD`  is `(String,String)`

```
val lines = sc.textFile("README.md")
val newRDD = lines.map(x => (x.split(" ")(0),x))
```

So, when I try to run`newRDD.values()` or `newRDD.keys()`, I get the error:

`error: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] does not take parameters newRDD.values()`or`.keys()` resp.

What I can understand from the error is maybe that `String` data type cannot be a key (And I think I am wrong). But if that's the case, why does
`newRDD.sortByKey()` work ?

Note: I am trying `values()` and `keys()` transformations because they're listed as valid transformations for one-pair RDDs

Edit: I am using Apache Spark version 1.5.2 in Scala

Comment: which version of Spark are you using?

Comment: Spark v1.5.2 using Scala

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't work `values` (or `keys`) receives no parameters and because of that it has to be called without parentheses:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(("foo", "bar")))

rdd.keys.first
// String = foo

rdd.values.first
// String = bar
```